# Excel, VBA, Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am needing some help.  I believe VBA is the only way to solve this issue but I may be wrong.

On Sheet1 in my workbook I have two columns that contain different items.  For instance in column B and column F contain different equipment items with a blank next to them for a quantity. It serves as a check list. Also on Sheet1 towards the top of the page are some conditional formatted check boxes that are selected for various "boxes" (ex: Box 1, Box 2, Box 3, etc.)

On Sheet2 there are different tables named for each box as mentioned above, and in the tables are different items.  These items may or may not be the same items in col B & F on Sheet1.

Purpose: I am hoping to learn to write code that says when selecting the conditional formatted check boxes next to the various boxes on Sheet 1, then it will highlight the items on sheet1 if it matches any item in the selected Box from Sheet2.

****I have updated my question with the below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

' In order to run code on sheet without a button or enabling in a module
Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is 
Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been changed.


Dim i, j As Integer
Dim box As String
Dim c As Range 'Define two ranges so that we can loop through both sheets to 
check the boxes
Dim d As Range
Sheets(1).Range("B11:B30, F11:F30").Font.ColorIndex = 0 'Remove the cell styles to apply new ones
box = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) 'This refers to the checkbox -  **QUESTION:How to have "multiple" check boxes to select from and will  run the same code?**
For i = 1 To 10 'Loop to find the checked box in sheet2
    If Sheets(2).Cells(1, i) = box Then 'Check for checked box
        For Each c In Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(2, i), Sheets(2).Cells(6, i))
            For Each d In Sheets(1).Range("B11:B30, F11:F30")
                If c = d Then
                    Sheets(1).Cells(d.Row, d.Column).Font.ColorIndex = 3 'changes matching item to red font
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    End If
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I see you're new here.  I would expect people to ask what you've tried and to show your attempts, which they're more inclined to help you with. Folks are always willing to help you understand what you're doing wrong, but they're often not willing to work to spec... from scratch.

Comment: I've inserted some code above but it is not ideal.  The problem is that I'm only seeing conditional format options but I know that is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood from your question I have written a code to format cell color. I have given the comments along with the code.

```
Sub format()
Dim i As Integer
Dim box As String
Dim c As Range 'Define two ranges so that we can loop through both sheets to check the boxes
Dim d As Range
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(50, 50)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'Remove the cell styles to apply new ones
box = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) 'This refers to the checkbox
For i = 1 To 10 'Loop to find the checked box in sheet2
    If Sheets(2).Cells(1, i) = box Then 'Check for checked box
        For Each c In Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(2, i), Sheets(2).Cells(20, i))
            For Each d In Sheets(1).Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(21, 21))
                If c = d Then
                    Sheets(1).Cells(d.Row, d.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'If true give yellow colour
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

And this is the excel sheet that I used [Excel Sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5tzpx5ldhum8k4/test.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Looks like I'm unable to access the excel sheet but I will give this a try and let you know... Thanks!

Comment: Try the Excel Sheet link now. I have activated it.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple check boxes.  For instance, have A1, A2, and A3 on sheet 1 do the same.  I was trying to figure this out but I keep getting an error

Comment: Could you provide more info or provide an excel sheet as you want or atleast a screen shot of the sheets..

Comment: SINAN NIZAR - please see more info below

Answer (score 0):

Please see below for code that I have so far.  It is a variation of what I received above.  I have posted the question on line 13.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

' In order to run code on sheet without a button or enabling in a module
Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is 
Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been changed.
    

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim box As String
Dim c As Range 'Define two ranges so that we can loop through both sheets to check the boxes
Dim d As Range
Sheets(1).Range("B11:B30, F11:F30").Font.ColorIndex = 0 'Remove the cell styles to apply new ones
box = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) 'This refers to the checkbox -  **QUESTION: How to have "multiple" check boxes to select from and will  run the same code?**
For i = 1 To 10 'Loop to find the checked box in sheet2
    If Sheets(2).Cells(1, i) = box Then 'Check for checked box
        For Each c In Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(2, i), Sheets(2).Cells(6, i))
            For Each d In Sheets(1).Range("B11:B30, F11:F30")
                If c = d Then
                    Sheets(1).Cells(d.Row, d.Column).Font.ColorIndex = 3 'changes matching item to red font
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    End If
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

[Sheet 1 Check boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdHe5.jpg) - I have conditional formatted check boxes which i can change.  They were based on a data validation list of 0,1 to change filling.  But I may have to change this.

**I have answered my own question.  Basically you can just have multiple strings box1, box2, etc. and write the same code for each string.  Not sure if this is the long way of doing it but it works.**